# Elevation animation on click on CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-elevation

I want to add the elevation animation to my `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`, just like the material style `Button`s do. I've tried to set a `StateListAnimator`:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@anim/selector_raise"
```

which points to my selector in `res/anim`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ" android:valueTo="@dimen/touch_raise"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <objectAnimator android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ" android:valueTo="0dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

but Android Studio gives me the error:

> Element selector must be declared

What's the right way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

You tried to create this .xml in `res/anim` folder.

You should create on `res/animator`, if don't exist is easy to create.

But if you search for the problem it already give you a possible solution
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've tried your code, maybe you have simply add the state to second selector element.

So change this line

```
<item>
```

with this

```
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false">
```

The complete code will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ" android:valueTo="@dimen/touch_raise"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false">
        <objectAnimator android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ" android:valueTo="0dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: worked for me, and I moved the animator under res/animator/my_filename.xml