# Android : How to set different elevation to each card in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am working on an android app in which I need to have the functionality of changing the order of cards in RecyclerView by drag and drop. Till now I am able to move cards by dragging them. But I am facing one issue, that is when I drag card below it goes behind the card that is below that card while when I move it up it comes ahead of the card above it as can be seen in the image.

[image]

I want that card that I am dragging to be always above other cards. So I tried providing extra elevation to the card that I am moving but still, the result is same. Below are snippets of code that are related to this part of my app.
**App's minimum SDK is 22**

card layout XML file. (file is too large to show here so this is an outline of it. Compressed views don't have any elevation attributes.)

[image]

The content of onTouch listener.

```
        moveButton.setOnTouchListener({v: View?, event: MotionEvent? ->
    if (v == null || event == null) return@setOnTouchListener true
    when (event.action){
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            v.performClick()
            pressUP(v,event)
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            pressDown(v,event)
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            pressMove(v,event)
        }
        else -> {
            null
        }
    }
    return@setOnTouchListener true
})

private fun pressDown(imageButton: View, event: MotionEvent){
    openedLayoutManagerLocal?.closeOpenedLayout()
    fragment.mLayoutManager?.setScrollEnabled(false)
    originalDelta = itemView.y
    _yDelta = itemView.y - event.rawY
    itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.elevation = elevation + 10 // as all layouts are by default elevated by 5
}

private fun pressUP(imageButton: View, event: MotionEvent){
    fragment.mLayoutManager?.setScrollEnabled(true)
    val a = itemView.animate()
            .y(originalDelta)
            .setDuration(100)
    a.setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener{
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
            itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.elevation = elevation + 5
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {

        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {

        }

        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
            itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.elevation = elevation + 5
        }
    })
    a.start()

}

private fun pressMove(imageButton: View, event: MotionEvent){
    itemView.animate()
            .y(event.rawY + _yDelta)
            .setDuration(0)
            .start()
}
```

So is there anything wrong with how I am assigning elevation?
I will also like to know if there is some other way to make this effect.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to use "andorid:elevation" for the cards and use an state animator, which increases the elevation via tranzlateZ in an animation like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43758592/2139738 , Another thing is, use the implemented way to drag recycler view items, explained here: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf

Comment: With this suggestions, you should be able to move your cards correctly ;)